# execute custom code while compilation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a program in WPF used to install a web ASP application on a server.

There are several steps to compile installer and I would like to make one solution.

Is it possible when I compile the solution, to execute custom code in order to minimize scripts and zip web application folders before compile installer project ?

Should I use pre-built events ?

For information the installer program is "home made" and I don't want to use another solution.

Thanks for your responses

Comment: wouldn't the post build event be more appropriate

Comment: what is your question anyway? are you asking for an [Alternative to Pre/Post Build Events in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550034/alternative-to-pre-post-build-events-in-visual-studio)?

Comment: I would like to execute code (in a class) for minimize scripts file and make a zip with bin, controller, views folders... when I compile ASP application and use the zip file to compile installer application

Comment: I found the solution, I use a msbuild Task which allow to execute code during compilation

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/t9883dzc.aspx